# Extract words between numbers

Tags: r, regex

Trying to write some `regex` in R to extract some words between numbers for each string in a character vector in R.  Unfortunately, my `regex` skills aren't nearly up to the challenge.
Here's an example of the problem and my initial attempt:

```
x <- c("1 Singleword 1,234 342", "2 randword & thirdword 1,545 323", 
      "3 Anotherword wordagain Newword. 3,234 556")

m <- regexpr("[a-zA-Z]+\\s+", x, perl = TRUE)

regmatches(x, m)
```

This approach only produces

```
"Singleword ", "randword ", "Anotherword "
```

What I need is

```
"Singleword", "randword & thirdword", "Anotherword wordagain Neword."
```

I believe it will need to be some kind of `regex` pattern that will start with a character (like I currently have) and then pull everything until a number is reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sub`

```
> sub(".\\s(\\D+).*", "\\1", x)
[1] "Singleword "   "randword & thirdword "  "Anotherword wordagain Newword. "
```

Using `str_extract`

```
> library(stringr)
> str_extract(x, pattern = "\\D+")
[1] " Singleword "  " randword & thirdword "  " Anotherword wordagain Newword. "
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x <- c("1 Singleword 1,234 342", "2 randword & thirdword 1,545 323", 
       "3 Anotherword wordagain Newword. 3,234 556")

m <- regexpr("[a-zA-Z].(\\D)+", x, perl = TRUE)

regmatches(x, m)
```

> [1] "Singleword "                     "randword & thirdword "
>       [3] "Anotherword wordagain Newword. "

I used https://regexr.com/ and it's cheatsheet to figure out how to compose the regex.

Comment: Works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

**sample data**

```
x <- c("1 Singleword 1,234 342", "2 randword & thirdword 1,545 323", 
   "3 Anotherword wordagain Newword. 3,234 556")
```

**Base R**

```
#replace als numbers and comma's with `""` (=nothing), 
# also, trim whitespaces (thanks Markus!)
trimws( gsub( "[0-9,]", "", x ) )
```

> [1] "Singleword"                     "randword & thirdword"           "Anotherword wordagain Newword."

**stringR**

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(x, pattern = "(?<=\\d )[^0-9]+(?= \\d)")
```

> [1] "Singleword" "randword & thirdword" "Anotherword wordagain Newword."

If you like to learn more about (the working of) regex-patterns in the code above (and in the other answers), check out their magic (and explanation) at: https://regex101.com/

explanation of the last regex-pattern: https://regex101.com/r/QgERuZ/2

Comment: You could wrap your `base R` solution in `trimws`, i.e. `trimws(gsub( "[0-9,]", "", x))` (sorry to bother you again).

Comment: `sub('. ([A-z].*?).\\d.*','\\1',x)`